# Haskell: Cannot install OpenGL due to missing dependencies (which are already installed there)

Tags: opengl, haskell, ubuntu, cabal, hackage

I am trying to install the OpenGL-2.4.0.2 package manually, but after I download the tarball from Hackage and decompressed it, when I ran

```
sudo runhaskell Setup.hs configure
```

I get these:

```
Configuring OpenGL-2.4.0.2...
Setup.hs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
GLURaw >=1.1.0.0,
ObjectName -any,
OpenGLRaw >=1.1.0.0,
StateVar -any,
Tensor -any
```

But I've checked that I've already installed these:

```
GLURaw 1.1.0.1
ObjectName 1.0.0.0
OpenGLRaw 1.1.0.2
StateVar 1.0.0.0
Tensor 1.0.0.1
```

And I've tried reinstall these but no avail.

I use GHC 7.2.1, cabal-install 0.8.0 with Cabal 1.8.0.2, under Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You are configuring as super user (why?).  Are the "missing" packages that you have installed actually installed globally or are they just in the users package config and thus not installed from the super-user's perspective?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: I tried both with sudo and without, but neither worked. Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: But you didn't answer the question.  iirc (it's been a while since I installed w/o cabal-install) the default is the global database.  If you have the packages installed locally then you need to explicitly specify the local package base via the `--user` flag.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Thanks! You and Daniel are both right. I apologize for my rather stupid question and not digging into the doc hard enough (or didn't "RTFM").

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, it is pretty confusing that the two ways have different defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the dependencies using cabal-install (the `cabal` command line programme), they are by default installed in the user package-db. But when you install a package using the `runhaskell ./Setup.hs` way, it does global installs by default and therefore cannot use packages from the user-db. Try installing the package in the user-db,

```
runhaskell ./Setup.hs configure --user
```

or reinstall the dependencies in the global db, `cabal install --global foo`.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: you can also just do "cabal configure", etc. in that directory rather than directly using "runhaskell Setup.hs".

Comment: @ZiyaoWei or even just `cabal install` in that directory if you don't need any special configuration parameters.